# How to get the records which is not equal to 1 in my query

Tags: sql-server

How to check the duplicated records in sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as long as where is executed before select, selected aliases are not known in where clause. you can only use the aliases in order by clause.

you have to write like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
Select TD.ProductAccumRule_Id,TD.PRODUCT_ID,TD.VARIABLE_ID,TD.Accum_code,Ordinal = row_number() over( partition by TD.PRODUCT_ID,TD.VARIABLE_ID,TD.Accum_code order by TD.PRODUCT_ID,TD.VARIABLE_ID,TD.Accum_code) From testdata TD
Join (
select PRODUCT_ID,VARIABLE_ID,Accum_code from testdata where 
isActive = 1
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID,VARIABLE_ID,Accum_code
having count(*) > 1
) TEMP on TD.Product_Id = temp.Product_Id and TD.Variable_Id = TEMP.Variable_Id and TD.Accum_code = TEMP.Accum_code
where TD.isActive = 1
) myInnerQuery
where Ordinal  <> 1
```

Answer (score 2):

There is always going to be a row_number() which is 1, right?

I think you need to nest this query like:

```
 select * from (YOUR_BIG_QUERY) where Ordinal <> 1
```

Comment: thanks Franco, I did that I am not able to get that. I am getting this Error. Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.